# Jest not able to find file import

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, next.js, ts-jest

`Jest` in my application is not able to find imported file and ends with this error:

> FAIL  pages_test_files/index.spec.js
>     ● Test suite failed to run
>       Cannot find module '../styles/sassTokenExports/colors.json' from 'index.js'
>       However, Jest was able to find:
>           '../pages/index.js'
>       You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'].
>       See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

I am using `Jest` in `nextJS` for Unit testing.

Comment: Have a similar issue. Any luck finding a solution?

Comment: @KhrystynaPochynok are you creating dynamic folders?

Comment: Yes this is quite a ridiculous problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. I had provided the absolute import path for the module I was trying to import and was receiving the same error. Turned out the base url for imports had been set in the config.
The base url was set to `./src` but I was including `./src` in my import like

`import myModule from './src/myFolder/myModule'`
which was the equivalent of

`'./src/src/myFolder/myModule'`.

I removed the `/src` and the error went away.

Some info here https://levelup.gitconnected.com/understand-and-configure-absolute-import-paths-in-javascript-5cde3be2630d